# How to pass str number in def python?

Tags: python

I have this program :

```
def test(zeit_1, zeit_2):
     zeit_1_liste = [int(x) for x in str(zeit_1)]            
     zeit_2_liste = [int(x) for x in str(zeit_2)]
     print(zeit_1_liste, zeit_2_liste)

print(test(160606,240000))
```

This program converts int to list of number. While it works very well when the input start by `>=1`, giving input number start with 0 (for example `060606` and `092618`) it will give me an invalid token error.

How can I solve this?

Comment: a leading 0 in python2 means octal, in python3 it is a syntax error, you would have to pass a string to use a leading 0 `print(test ("060606","040000"))` or `0o60606...`, a 0 followed by a `o`

Comment: Could you be more specific about the problem you're trying to solve? Your question title and the code you posted seem incompatible.

Answer (score 2):

In python3, integer literals cannot consist of a `0` followed by other digits:

```
>>> a = 0123
    a = 0123
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid token
```

If you really want octal literals, you need to start them with `0o`. But is seems you want decimals anyway, in which case you need to remove the leading `0`s.

---

**Note**: In python2, integer literals starting with `0` followed by other digits are *octal*, or base-8. That means that they can only be composed of digits in the range `[0, 8]`. `060606` satisfies this criteria:

```
>>> [int(x) for x in str(060606)]
[2, 4, 9, 6, 6]
```

but `092618` doesn't.

```
>>> [int(x) for x in str(092618)]
    [int(x) for x in str(092618)]

SyntaxError: invalid token
```

Comment: The OP is using python3 where you cannot use a leading 0

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Oh, I see that octal literals have a different representation in python3. That makes sense. I will remove this or re-work it.

Comment: I think the OP may not realise that they are using octal so the answer is still relevant, if they do then adding a `o` after the 0 will do the trick

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I suspect they want decimal, because they tried `092618`, but I think there is enough information in the answer now for them to figure out how to solve their problem.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put it in string:

```
print(test("160606", "240000"))
```

Comment: I think this doesn't solve OP's problem. But however, this is the **only best** solution. I'll upvote for this.

Comment: @KevinGuan why do you think it does not solve the OP's problem, though?

Comment: It would certainly make the function quite pointless, since converting a string to a list is trivial.

Comment: @dopstar Because OP wants covert numbers to string inside that function, so I think this way is works, but as  juanchopanza said, *since converting a string to a list is trivial.*

Comment: But its not about trival or non-trivial. The question from the OP is 'How to pass str number to def in python?'. This solution passes numbers as strings to a function as asked. Simple like that.

Comment: @dopstar Yeah, this is the easiest and works way. But maybe this isn't OP's looking for and it doesn't really solve OP's problem(about `test(160606, 240000)`). So I upvoted for this, and posted that comment. That's what I mean.

Comment: @dopstar Simple as that? What you quoted isn't clear ("pass str number to def" isn't a thing), but the code sample suggests that OP wants to pass integer literals and have them converted to lists of characters. So I guess this question should be filed under "unclear what you are asking" until OP explains what they are actually trying to solve.

Comment: @juanchopanza I thought 'str' is a python way to say string and 'def' a python way to say 'function' leaving the technicals aside. So this means passing numbers as strings to a function. How the function is being implemented its another story. Its like we look inside a function implementation and ignore the actual question that was asked and rather focus on trivial and non-trivial concerns and start assuming what the OP *might* be looking for. My concern is to assert the answer as *not solving the problem* and then also claim that its the *only best* solution. Contradiction.

Comment: This is what i was looking for :D thanks for the solution.

Comment: @maxime Please clarify your question. It should be understandable by future readers.